# Implement OpenGl-like MIRRORED_REPEAT

Tags: c++, indexing

I am supposed to implement a MIRRORED_REPEAT for my raytracing textures. I looked at how it's defined in OpenGL https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf page 260 and then I tried it myself, first with a 1-dimesional array. The behaviour should be: [image: returns x]

Basically it repeats the index into the array ( modulo ) but mirrors the input based on wether or not the offset is even or odd. ( 2nd image below )
[image]

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int values[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    const auto mod = [](const int a, const int n) noexcept
    {
        return (a % n + n) % n;
    };

    const auto mirror = [](const int a) noexcept
    {
        return a >= 0.f ? a : -(1 + a);
    };

    const auto mirrored_repeat = [&](const int x) noexcept {
        return (10 - 1) - mirror(mod(x, 2 * 10)) - 10;
    };

    for(int i = -5; i < 6; ++i) {
        std::cout << values[mirrored_repeat(i)] << std::endl;   
    }
}
```

This doesn't work however, but gives me nice undefined-behaviourish output instead x) Can someone tell me how I can do it properly?

Comment: reason for close vote?

Comment: You post is decent, but it would help if you provided the actual output and the desired output. (NB: I am not the downvoter)

Comment: well the current output is different every time cause the indexes are out of bounds, but I added 2 pictures to clarify what's supposed to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the line

```
std::cout << values[mirrored_repeat(i)] << std::endl;
```

with

```
std::cout << mirrored_repeat(i) << std::endl;
```

you'll see that the indices returned by `mirrored_repeat` are clearly wrong (they are negative, to begin with).

I believe the formula in the spec is a bit wrong, for it has one mismatched bracket. If we rewrite the line

```
return (10 - 1) - mirror(mod(x, 2 * 10)) - 10;
```

like this

```
return (10 - 1) - mirror(mod(x, 2 * 10) - 10);
```

the code starts producing something more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I derived a shorter solution while working on Blender:

C++

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const auto mirrored_repeat = [&](int x, const int size) noexcept {
        x = std::abs(x + (x < 0)) % (2 * size);
        return x >= size ? 2 * size - x - 1 : x;
    };

    for (int i = -6; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << mirrored_repeat(i, 10) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

JavaScript demo

```js
function mirrored_repeat(x, size) {
    x = Math.abs(x + (x < 0)) % (2 * size);
    return x >= size ? 2 * size - x - 1 : x;
}

for (let i = -6; i < 5; ++i) {
    console.log(mirrored_repeat(i, 10));
}
```

I wanted to reduce the number of modulo calls, so I used the symmetry of C++ modulo for odd sections and the if statement for even sections.

For information on how I derived it, [see my explanation here](https://developer.blender.org/D16432).